# Microsoft Dynamics NAV licensing

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

I am running an application with 50 perpetual licenses. To save on costs I want to go for Subscription model for my further license requirements. Is it possible for both to co-exist in the same application?

Answer (score 2):

No, Perpetual and Subscription are 2 separate types of licenses specified when creating a license on Microsoft website.

Perpetual is pay-once license. You pay the costs up-front and have the license in perpetuity. Subscription license requires ongoing payments and you lose licensing rights if you do not pay.

The license type is written into the license file when created and only one license file can be loaded against the database.

See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn892088(v=nav.90).aspx
(scroll down to License model)